# How do you split string at current position?

Tags: java

I am trying to split a line of text after every instance of '|', however I cant seem to figure it out. Here is what i have got so far

```
char special = '|';
for (int i = 0; i < blobs.length(); i++)
{
  if(blobs.charAt(i) == special)
  {
    String[] splitwords = blobs.split(charAt(i));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use blobs.split("\|")

```
String[] split = blobs.split("\\|");
```

Comment: When i just do this it splits after the first character instead of the actual "|"

Comment: @yeshello: Suppose the string is I|am|java, the output array would be [I, am, java]. Do you not want that?

Comment: That is what i want, but for some reason when i call split[2] for example, i would just get 'm' instead of 'Java'. Is there any code to split after any use of a special character?

Comment: @yeshello: My bad, use this instead String[] split = blobs.split("\\|");
In java you need to escape the special characters using "\\"

Answer (score 2):

First, your code will split things, but puts it into a local variable, which isn't visible outside of that one if block. That simply doesn't make any sense.

But well, you dont need any of that. `split()` doesn't split at **positions**.

That method takes your *split* character, and splits the whole string accordingly.

Simply try

```
"some|string|with|pipes".split('|')
```

for example. If your question is: how could I split "sub strings", well: then you will have to first dissect your input string into multiple substrings, and then call `split()` on those different strings accordingly.

Beyond that: don't try to *assume* what such library methods do.

Get a good book or tutorial and **research** them, see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this problem. You can simply do:

`String[] splitBlobs = blobs.split('|')`

This will return a list of strings with each element being before and after `'|'` but not the actual character.

Comment: Sorry I have been helping with Python a lot recently and have been mixing conventions I will go ahead and make the edit @GhostCat